# Trying a push-notifications/Node.js tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification

I am trying to figure out how to use `push-notifications` within a `Node.js` app. Now following this tutorial: https://thihara.github.io/Web-Push/.

I have passed the point where I can see the **Enable Push Messaging** button, I clicked the button and now I see the **Subscribe to push notifications** button.
When I click this last button it changes to **Unsubscribe from push notifications**, and if I click it again it changes back to **Subscribe to push notifications** and so on, but nothing else happens.

Has anyone else explored this tutorial? I'd be glad if I could get some advice on how to move forward.

Comment: Send messages maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "send messages"? I suppose I should see some notifications firing. But I guess, only someone who has tried the tutorial before me could tell me what to do or where to look at.

Comment: He means keep reading and following your tutorial, based on your description you still have a lot of reading to do in that article.